# IEDriverServer executable remains after Selenium fails

Tags: java, selenium

Using Selenium version 2.44 and IE version 11.0.9600.17728

If the driver constructor fails because of Protected Mode settings, the EXE remains running.

It seems the quit call cleans things up when everything worked, but since the driver is never constructed this can not be used.

Is it possible to stop the EXE when the constructor throw the exception?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class SeleniumTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.44.0.exe");

        try
        {
            InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
            driver.quit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            /*
             * To cause this, change the following IE settings:
             * 
             * On tab: Internet Options->Security
             * 
             * Make sure the four zones do not have the same value for "Enabled Protected Mode"
             */
            System.err.println("Failed making the driver");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The output I see when I run the above code:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.44.0.0
Listening on port 9550
Failed making the driver
org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.67 seconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23 13:11:40'
System info: host: 'T7610', ip: '192.168.0.11', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:225)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:146)
    at SeleniumTest.main(SeleniumTest.java:23)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the following piece of code in the catch block.

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Driver gets instantiated even the test catches the exception. The exception happens when you are trying to navigate to the url and in the meantime the driver is already instantiated. So call the quit inside the catch block and that will do the work you want.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class SeleniumTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.44.0.exe");

        try
        {
            InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.get("http://www.google.com");
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
            driver.quit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            /*
             * To cause this, change the following IE settings:
             * 
             * On tab: Internet Options->Security
             * 
             * Make sure the four zones do not have the same value for "Enabled Protected Mode"
             */
            driver.quit();
            System.err.println("Failed making the driver");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my environment, the driver IS NOT instantiated.  The failure occurs during instantiation.  As such, I do not have a driver to call quit on (as the original post says).

Comment: Can you provide the exact stack trace in that case then?